# Webservice and Android with ksoap2 written in Kotlin

Tags: android, soap, kotlin, android-ksoap2

Hello together I've been trying to rebuild the tempconverter webservice of w3 school for some time now. This also works quite well so far. However, when accessing my server from my Android app I get the following error message:

> SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://soapservicetest/", local:"input"). Expected elements are <{}input> ' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

My Code looks like this:

```
fun getResultFromInput(input: Int?){
    //new SoapRequest soapRequest = new SoapRequest; SoapReq
    val request = SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME)
    val celsiusPI = PropertyInfo()
    celsiusPI.setName("input")
    celsiusPI.value = input
    celsiusPI.setType(Double::class.javaPrimitiveType)
    request.addProperty(celsiusPI)
    val envelope = SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11
    )
    envelope.env = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    envelope.bodyOut = request
    envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC2003
    envelope.dotNet = true
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request)
    val androidHttpTransport = HttpTransportSE(URL)
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope)
        response = responseLocal.toString()
    }catch (e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }catch (t: SocketTimeoutException) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    } catch (i: IOException) {
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The SoapFault is caught in the Exception catch block but I did not get any response of my Webservice. But if I test it with for example wsdlbrowser.com everything is working fine.

Somebody got an Idea and can help me out?